# Help with matrix selection in matlab

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, matlab, positive-semidefinite

I have this equalities, with $\Delta X$ and $\Delta S$ unknown matrices, $X$, $S$ and $\tau$ known. $$W^{-1}\Delta X W^{-1}+\Delta S=\tau X^{-1}-S$$or equivalently  $$\Delta X + W\Delta S W=\tau S^{-1}-X$$

My first question is how can i compute, or how can i find $\Delta X$.

My second question is, that given the following sets: $$N_\mathcal{F}(\theta):=\{(X,y,S)\in\mathcal{F}^0 : d_\mathcal{F}(X,S)\leq\theta\mu(X,S)\}$$
and $$\mathcal{F}^0:=\{(X,y,S):\textbf{tr}(A_iX)=b_i; \sum_{i=1}^my_iA_i+S=C; X,S\succ 0\;, i=1,...,m\}$$
Wher $\theta, C, A_i$ are given, and $$d_\mathcal{F}(X,S)=||S^{1/}2XS^{1/2}-\mu(X,S)I||_F$$ $$\mu(X,S)=\textbf{tr}(XS)/n$$
With $n=size(X)$.

How can i find, or compute in matlab, a fesasible pair $(X^0,S^0)\in N_\mathcal{F}(\theta)$

Comment: Its better to split these questions into two threads. Regarding your first question, it is not obvious that these equations are equivalent, please clarify.

Comment: I agree with @Adrian Schad : there is first a question of equivalence ; besides, we don't know the status of $\Delta S$. If it is known, we would have plainly $$\Delta X = -W\Delta S W+\tau S^{-1}-X...$$ Otherwise you are looking for an unknown  pair $(\Delta X,\Delta S)$. Is that the right interpretation ?